# Android webView to play YouTube videos

Tags: android, webview, youtube, embed

can anyone help using this code to get youtube videos to play that are embedded in website?
have tried all sorts of things including hardwareAccelerated=true in manifest.

The webview shows the youtube page and thumbnail images but when clicking on them nothing happens.

On certain devices with hardwareAccelerated it plays the sound but no video.
thanks everyone!

```
package com.inglesupdated;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Picture;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebView.PictureListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class BT_screen_customURL extends BT_activity_base{

    private boolean didCreate = false;
    private WebView webView = null;
    private String dataURL = "";
    private String currentURL = "";
    private String originalURL = "";
    private AlertDialog confirmLaunchInNativeAppDialogue = null;
    private AlertDialog confirmEmailDocumentDialogue = null;

    private String showBrowserBarBack = "";
    private String showBrowserBarLaunchInNativeApp = "";
    private String showBrowserBarEmailDocument = "";
    private String showBrowserBarRefresh = "";

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //activity life-cycle events.

    //onCreate
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.activityName = "BT_screen_customURL";
        BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":onCreate"); 

        //reference to base layout..
        LinearLayout baseView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.baseView);

        //setup background colors...
        BT_viewUtilities.updateBackgroundColorsForScreen(this, this.screenData);

        //setup background images..
        if(backgroundImageWorkerThread == null){
            backgroundImageWorkerThread = new BackgroundImageWorkerThread();
            backgroundImageWorkerThread.start();
        }           

        //setup navigation bar...
        LinearLayout navBar = BT_viewUtilities.getNavBarForScreen(this, this.screenData);
        if(navBar != null){
            baseView.addView(navBar);
        }

        //inflate this screens layout file...
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)thisActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View thisScreensView = vi.inflate(R.layout.screen_customurl, null);


        //add the view to the base view...
        baseView.addView(thisScreensView);

        //reference to the webview in the layout file.

        webView = (WebView) thisScreensView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setBackgroundColor(0);
        webView.setInitialScale(0);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webView.setPictureListener(new MyPictureListener()); 
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){

                //remember the URL...
                currentURL = url;

                //load the URL in the app's built-in browser if it's in our list of types to load...
                if(BT_act_controller.canLoadDocumentInWebView(url)){

                    //load url in built-in browser...
                //  showProgress(null, null);
                    return false;                   


                }else{

                    //ask user what app to open this in if the method returned NO...
                    try{
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, getString(R.string.openWithWhatApp)));  
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ": Error launching native app for url: " + url);
                        showAlert(getString(R.string.noNativeAppTitle), getString(R.string.noNativeAppDescription));
                    }

                    //do not try to load the URL..
                    return true;                    


                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
                hideProgress();
                BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":onPageFinished finished Loading: " + url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                hideProgress();
                showAlert(getString(R.string.errorTitle), getString(R.string.errorLoadingScreen));
                BT_debugger.showIt(activityName = ":onReceivedError ERROR loading url: " + failingUrl + " Description: " + description);
            }           

        }); 


        //fill JSON properties...
        dataURL = BT_strings.getJsonPropertyValue(this.screenData.getJsonObject(), "dataURL", "");
        currentURL = dataURL;
        originalURL = dataURL;

        //button options for hardware menu key...
        showBrowserBarBack = BT_strings.getJsonPropertyValue(this.screenData.getJsonObject(), "showBrowserBarBack", "0");
        showBrowserBarLaunchInNativeApp = BT_strings.getJsonPropertyValue(this.screenData.getJsonObject(), "showBrowserBarLaunchInNativeApp", "0");
        showBrowserBarEmailDocument = BT_strings.getJsonPropertyValue(this.screenData.getJsonObject(), "showBrowserBarEmailDocument", "0");
        showBrowserBarRefresh = BT_strings.getJsonPropertyValue(this.screenData.getJsonObject(), "showBrowserBarRefresh", "0");


        //prevent user interaction?
        String preventUserInteraction = BT_strings.getJsonPropertyValue(this.screenData.getJsonObject(), "preventUserInteraction", "0");
        if(preventUserInteraction.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            //can't seem to get Android to "prevent user interaction"...??? 
        }

        //hide scroll bars..
        String hideVerticalScrollBar = BT_strings.getJsonPropertyValue(this.screenData.getJsonObject(), "hideVerticalScrollBar", "0");
        if(hideVerticalScrollBar.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        }
        String hideHorizontalScrollBar = BT_strings.getJsonPropertyValue(this.screenData.getJsonObject(), "hideHorizontalScrollBar", "0");
        if(hideHorizontalScrollBar.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        }
        String preventAllScrolling = BT_strings.getJsonPropertyValue(this.screenData.getJsonObject(), "preventAllScrolling", "0");
        if(preventAllScrolling.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        }       


        //figure out what to load...
        if(dataURL.length() > 1){

            String useUrl = BT_strings.mergeBTVariablesInString(dataURL);
            BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ": loading URL from: " + useUrl);
            this.loadUrl(useUrl);

        }else{
            BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ": No URL found? Not loading web-view!");
            showAlert(getString(R.string.errorTitle), getString(R.string.errorLoadingScreen));
        }


        //flag as created..
        didCreate = true;

        /*
         * *******************************************************************

         Notes: This screen has fully loaded it's layout file at this point. 

         BT_activity_base loaded act_base.xml 
         --THEN--
         this screen loaded it's own layout file. 

         JSON properties for this screen from the app's configuration data are 
         available for use. You can read these properties easily using the BT_strings class.

         Example: 
         String thisScreensNavBarTitleText = BT_strings.getJsonPropertyValue(this.screenData.getJsonObject(), "thisScreensNavBarTitleText", "default value here");

         The screens background and title bar were setup using the BT_viewUtilities class:
         BT_viewUtilities.updateBackgroundColorsForScreen() 

         You are free to modify the layout file and extend this screen however you want. 

         ********************************************************************
        */      



    }//onCreate

    //onStart
    @Override 
    protected void onStart() {
        //BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":onStart");    
        super.onStart();
    }

    //onResume
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
        //BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":onResume");

       //verify onCreate already ran...
       if(didCreate){

       }

    }

    //onPause
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":onPause");    
    }

    //onStop
    @Override 
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        //BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":onStop"); 
    }   

    //onDestroy
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":onDestroy");  
    }

    //end activity life-cycle events
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    //load URL in webView
    public void loadUrl(String theUrl){
        BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ": loadUrl");
        try{
            webView.loadUrl(theUrl);
        }catch(Exception e){
            BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":loadUrl Exception: " + e.toString());
        }
    }



    /*  Hardware Back-Key, uncomment as needed.
        Uncomment this to make the hardware back-key act like a browser back button
        Warning: If you do this the user will need to go "back" the number of times they
        when "forward" to return to the previous screen.
        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()){
                webView.goBack();
                return true;
            }
            //not the back-key..
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
    */

    //back button...
    public void handleBackButton(){
        BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":handleBackButton");
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }else{
            BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":handleBackButton cannot go back?");
        }
    }

    //refresh button...
    public void handleRefreshButton(){
        BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":handleRefreshButton");
        if(currentURL.length() > 1){
            showProgress(null, null);
            webView.loadUrl(currentURL);
        }else{
            BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":handleRefreshButton cannot refresh?");
        }
    }

    //launch in native app button...
    public void handleLaunchInNativeAppButton(){
        BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":handleLaunchInNativeAppButton");
        if(currentURL.length() > 1 && originalURL.length() > 1){
            confirmLaunchInNativeApp();
        }else{
            showAlert(getString(R.string.errorTitle), getString(R.string.cannotOpenDocumentInNativeApp));
            BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":handleLaunchInNativeAppButton NO url?");
        }
    }

    //handle email button
    public void handleEmailDocumentButton(){
        BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":handleLaunchInNativeAppButton");
        showAlert(getString(R.string.errorTitle), getString(R.string.cannotEmailDocument));
        BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":handleEmailDocumentButton NO  document to email on URL screens");
    }

    //confirm launch in native app
    public void confirmLaunchInNativeApp(){
        confirmLaunchInNativeAppDialogue = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        confirmLaunchInNativeAppDialogue.setTitle(getString(R.string.confirm));
        confirmLaunchInNativeAppDialogue.setMessage(getString(R.string.confirmLaunchInNativeBrowser));
        confirmLaunchInNativeAppDialogue.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);

        //YES
        confirmLaunchInNativeAppDialogue.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, getString(R.string.yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              confirmLaunchInNativeAppDialogue.dismiss();

              //tell Android to load the URL in the best available Native App...
                try{
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(currentURL));
                    startActivity(i);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ": Error launching native app for url: " + currentURL);
                    showAlert(getString(R.string.noNativeAppTitle), getString(R.string.noNativeAppDescription));
                }             
        } }); 

        //NO
        confirmLaunchInNativeAppDialogue.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, getString(R.string.no), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                confirmLaunchInNativeAppDialogue.dismiss();
            } }); 

        //show the confirmation box...
        confirmLaunchInNativeAppDialogue.show();
    }       

    //confirm email document
    public void confirmEmailDocumentDialogue(){
        confirmEmailDocumentDialogue = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        confirmEmailDocumentDialogue.setTitle(getString(R.string.confirm));
        confirmEmailDocumentDialogue.setMessage(getString(R.string.confirmEmailDocument));
        confirmEmailDocumentDialogue.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);

        //YES
        confirmEmailDocumentDialogue.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, getString(R.string.yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              confirmEmailDocumentDialogue.dismiss();

              //tell Android launch the native email application...
              Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
              emailIntent.setType("plain/text");  
              emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.sharingWithYou));  
              emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, currentURL);                

              //chooser will propmpt user if they have more than one email client..
              startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getString(R.string.openWithWhatApp)));  

        } }); 

        //NO
        confirmEmailDocumentDialogue.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, getString(R.string.no), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                confirmEmailDocumentDialogue.dismiss();
            } }); 

        //show the confirmation box...
        confirmEmailDocumentDialogue.show();
    }       


    //see webView (above) where onPageFinished is loading too soon...
    class MyPictureListener implements PictureListener {
        public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture arg1) {
            //BT_debugger.showIt("here" + ":onNewPicture done");
            hideProgress();      
        }    
    }


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //options menu (hardware menu-button)
    @Override 
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu); 

         //set up dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

        //linear layout holds all the options...
        LinearLayout optionsView = new LinearLayout(this);
        optionsView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        optionsView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        optionsView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        optionsView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 20);

        //options have individual layout params
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams btnLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(400, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        btnLayoutParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        btnLayoutParams.leftMargin = 10;
        btnLayoutParams.rightMargin = 10;
        btnLayoutParams.topMargin = 0;
        btnLayoutParams.bottomMargin = 10;

        //holds all the options 
        ArrayList<Button> options = new ArrayList<Button>();

        //cancel...
        final Button btnCancel = new Button(this);
        btnCancel.setText(getString(R.string.okClose));

        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        options.add(btnCancel);

        //back...
        if(showBrowserBarBack.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            final Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setText(getString(R.string.browserBack));
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    dialog.cancel();
                    handleBackButton();
                }
            });
            options.add(btn);
        }

        //launch in native app...
        if(showBrowserBarLaunchInNativeApp.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            final Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setText(getString(R.string.browserOpenInNativeApp));
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    dialog.cancel();
                    handleLaunchInNativeAppButton();
                }
            });
            options.add(btn);
        }   

        //email document...
        if(showBrowserBarEmailDocument.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            final Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setText(getString(R.string.browserEmailDocument));
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    dialog.cancel();
                    handleEmailDocumentButton();
                }
            });
            options.add(btn);
        }

        //refresh page...
        if(showBrowserBarRefresh.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            final Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setText(getString(R.string.browserRefresh));
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    dialog.cancel();
                    handleRefreshButton();
                }
            });
            options.add(btn);
        }       

        //refreshAppData (if we are on home screen)
        if(this.screenData.isHomeScreen() && inglesupdated_appDelegate.rootApp.getDataURL().length() > 1){

            final Button btnRefreshAppData = new Button(this);
            btnRefreshAppData.setText(getString(R.string.refreshAppData));
            btnRefreshAppData.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    dialog.cancel();
                    refreshAppData();
                }
            });
            options.add(btnRefreshAppData);         
        }       

        //add each option to layout, set layoutParams as we go...
        for(int x = 0; x < options.size(); x++){
            options.get(x).setLayoutParams(btnLayoutParams);
            options.get(x).setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            optionsView.addView(options.get(x));
        }


        //set content view..        
        dialog.setContentView(optionsView);
        if(options.size() > 1){
            dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.menuOptions));
        }else{
            dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.menuNoOptions));
        }
        //show
        dialog.show();
        return true;

    } 
    //end options menu
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////   






}
```

Comment: Are you trying in physical phone or in the emulator?

Comment: It is better to use youtube android API.
read here https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Answer (score 17):

After 3 days trying to play Youtube videos inside a WebView using different solutions found along 10 Google search pages, some solutions work but not on every device or os version, I decided to think my own way.

For me, the solution of playing the video directly on the WebView generates many artifacts even on the last Android device : Nexus 4
So, I had to find a way to catch the click on the Youtube iframe in order to launch the Youtube application directly like iOS do perfectly without any developer efforts.

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    public Activity mActivity;

    public MyWebViewClient(Activity activity) {
        super();
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        if (uri.getHost().contains("youtube.com")) {
            IntentUtils.viewYoutube(mActivity, url);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void viewYoutube(Context context, String url) {
        IntentUtils.viewWithPackageName(context, url, "com.google.android.youtube");
    }

    public static void viewWithPackageName(Context context, String url, String packageName) {
        try {
            Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            if (isAppInstalled(context, packageName)) {
                viewIntent.setPackage(packageName);
            }
            context.startActivity(viewIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            context.startActivity(viewIntent);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isAppInstalled(Context context, String packageName) {
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        try {
            packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            return true;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {
        String javascript = "javascript:" +
            "var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');" +
            "for (var i = 0, l = iframes.length; i < l; i++) {" +
            "   var iframe = iframes[i]," +
            "   a = document.createElement('a');" +
            "   a.setAttribute('href', iframe.src);" +
            "   d = document.createElement('div');" +
            "   d.style.width = iframe.offsetWidth + 'px';" +
            "   d.style.height = iframe.offsetHeight + 'px';" +
            "   d.style.top = iframe.offsetTop + 'px';" +
            "   d.style.left = iframe.offsetLeft + 'px';" +
            "   d.style.position = 'absolute';" +
            "   d.style.opacity = '0';" +
            "   d.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=0)';" +
            "   d.style.background = 'black';" +
            "   a.appendChild(d);" +
            "   iframe.offsetParent.appendChild(a);" +
            "}";
        view.loadUrl(javascript);

        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}
```

By the way I have to say that I'm a little bit upset of the few efforts made to provide an acceptable WebView to developers.

Even if I understand the wish to avoid Android applications only based on HTML, it's always the best/quickest way to display rich content on a details page.
For example, in my case, I manage an RSS based application which allows my customers to change the content themselves.

Also, looking at the time we have to spend for linking the UI with network data and saved data comparing to Windows Phone development where every data is directly linking to an UI component.

Comment: please, how can I use this class

Comment: What is IntentUtils?

Answer (score 2):

Thomas G.'s solution worked for me however I had to modify the javascript.

```
String javascript = "javascript:" +
                "setTimeout(function() {" +
                "   var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');" +
                "   for (var i = 0, l = iframes.length; i < l; i++) {" +
                "       var iframe = iframes[i]," +
                "       a = document.createElement('a');" +
                "       a.setAttribute('href', iframe.src);" +
                "       d = document.createElement('div');" +
                "       d.style.width = iframe.offsetWidth + 'px';" +
                "       d.style.height = iframe.offsetHeight + 'px';" +
                "       d.style.top = iframe.offsetTop + 'px';" +
                "       d.style.left = iframe.offsetLeft + 'px';" +
                "       d.style.position = 'absolute';" +
                "       d.style.opacity = '0';" +
                "       d.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=0)';" +
                "       d.style.zIndex='" + Integer.MAX_VALUE + "';" +
                "       d.style.background = 'black';" +
                "       a.appendChild(d);" +
                "       iframe.offsetParent.appendChild(a);" +
                "   }" +
                "}, 600);";
```

Executing the javascript a little bit after the onPageFinished event fixed an issue on a Samsung Tab device which didn't seem to be ready if the js executed immediately. I tried the onload event / $(document).ready but still didn't work. Waiting 600 ms isn't ideal but I've already spent enough time trying to get this to work.

Making sure the z-index is greater than that of the iframe, the easiest approach is setting the zIndex to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`